# How to remove special characters in URL during Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, submission

I am trying to remove the special characters during form submission in PHP. Everytime I want to submit a data for example :

```
<form action="?" method="get">
<input type="text" name="str" value="I want to remove this" />
</form>
```

the output in the browser looks like this

```
http://localhost/?str=I+want+to+remove+this
```

Is there anyway that we can get rid of those "+" before submission or during submission?

My expected result is

```
http://localhost/?str=I want to remove this
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the url you cannot have empty spaces, on the server side

```
str=I+want+to+remove+this
```

will be read as

```
str=I want to remove this
```

only. So i do not think you really need to worry about that encoding.